# Можно ли пробежать по внутреннему массиву в списке ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Есть список
`public static List<Note> noteList = new ArrayList<>();`

Создается объект Note в списке ArrayList, в котором есть id, text и отдельный массив labels.

`String[] labels = scn.nextLine().toUpperCase().split(" ");`

В методе при создании объекта возвращается:

`return new Note(IdInit.newId(), text, labels);`

Возможно ли пробежаться по массиву labels внутри списка и вывести объекты с определенными метками labels?
Например, если ввести метку = "важно", то выводятся все объекты, где есть метка "важно".

Comment: Конечно можно, а почему нельзя? Идём по списку, для очередного элемента получаем массив `labels`. Проходимся по нему, если содержит метку - выводим, видимо, `Note`.

Comment: @Byb Не подскажите, как для очередного элемента получить массив labels? А то мне советуют переписывать лист на HashMap)

Comment: Добавить в класс `Note` метод-геттер, который будет возвращать массив

Comment: Спасибо, попытаюсь!

Comment: При помощи геттера в классе Note например: `public String[] getLabels() {return labels; }`... `note.getLabels()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При наличии геттера для поля `labels` в классе `Note`, проверку можно выполнить так, преобразовывая массив в множество при помощи метода [`Set.of(E ... elements)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E...)) (Java 11+), что позволит применить быстрый метод поиска `Set::contains`

```java
String label = "важно";
for (Note note : noteList) {
    if (Set.of(note.getLabels()).contains()) {
        System.out.println(note);
    }
}
```

Аналогично, можно воспользоваться Stream API:

- Преобразовывая массив меток в поток и применяя `Stream::anyMatch` (решение для Java 8)

```java
noteList.stream() // Stream<Note>
    .filter(note -> Arrays.stream(note.getLabels()).distinct().anyMatch(search::equals))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

- Используя аналогичное преобразование в сет:

```java
noteList.stream() // Stream<Note>
    .filter(note -> Set.of(note.getLabels()).contains(search))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: *"решение для Java 8"* - ¿Оно случаем не страдает от дополнительного оверхеда?

Comment: Можно добавить `distinct()` перед `anyMatch` для зловредного случая массива меток с кучей дубликатов.

Comment: Я имел ввиду оверхед от использования stream API.